# return results of same ID from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I'm using an opensource database, so it's setup is a bit over my head.

Its basically like this.
A persons normal information is in the table 'person_per'
There is custom information in the table 'person_custom'

both use 'per_ID' to organize.

```
select per_ID from person_custom where c3 like '2';
```

gives my the IDs of people who fit my search, I want to "join" (I think) their name, phone, ect from the 'person_per' table using the ID as the "key"(terms I read that seem to fit).

How can I do that in a single query?

Comment: Have you searched the documentation on the term "Join"? I think it will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: I did search Join, the answers that I got seemed like they would work, but that assumed much more understanding than I have. So I couldn't do anything with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select per.*
from person_per per
inner join person_custom cus on cus.per_id = per.per_id
where cus.c3 = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all the columns from both tables with a single query:

```
SELECT p.name
     , p.phone
     , p.ect
     , c.custom_col
  FROM person_per p
  JOIN person_custom c
    ON c.per_ID = p.per_ID
 WHERE c.c3 LIKE '2'
```

Use a `JOIN` operator between the table names, and include the "matching" criteria (predicate) in the `ON` clause.